# vaadin 8 bakery app login

Tags: java-ee, servlet, vaadin, login

Я использую vaadin 8 + tomcat 7. На сайте vaadin представлено [демонстрационное приложение bakery](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/bakeryfw8/overview.html).

Конкретно в нём меня интересует процесс логирования. Там представлен отдельный сервлет LoginHtmlServlet, который каким-то образом работает с самим приложением vaadin, вот его код:

```
@WebServlet(asyncSupported = true, urlPatterns = LoginHtmlServlet.LOGIN_HTML)
public class LoginHtmlServlet extends HttpServlet implements HasLogger {

    public static final String LOGIN_HTML = "/login.html";

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        serveLoginHtml(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (req.getAttribute("shiroLoginFailure") != null) {
            try {
                resp.sendRedirect(LOGIN_HTML + "?error");
                return;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                getLogger().error("Failed to redirect to login error page", e);
            }
        }
        serveLoginHtml(req, resp);
    }

    private void serveLoginHtml(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        InputStream loginHtml = request.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(LOGIN_HTML);
        response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
        org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(loginHtml, response.getOutputStream());

    }
}
```

Так же присутствует страница login.html на которую ссылается LoginHtmlServlet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- 
Hint to Vaadin that if this page is ever sent back as response to a UIDL request, the user should be redirected.

Vaadin-Refresh: context://login.html
-->
<head>
  <title>My Starter Project</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="VAADIN/themes/apptheme/favicon.ico" />
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/vaadin-valo-theme/color.html"> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no">
  
  <!-- Enable these to hide browser controls when app is started from homescreen:
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  -->
    
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var init = function() {
      if (window.location.search.indexOf("error")>0) {
          document.body.className = "error";
      }
    }
    
  </script>
 <style>
  @font-face {
   font-family: "Open Sans";
   src: url(VAADIN/themes/valo/fonts/open-sans/OpenSans-Light-webfont.woff) format("woff");
   font-weight: 300;
   font-style: normal;
  }
  @font-face {
   font-family: "Open Sans";
   src: url(VAADIN/themes/valo/fonts/open-sans/OpenSans-Semibold-webfont.woff) format("woff");
   font-weight: 600;
   font-style: normal;
  }
  
    html {
     background: linear-gradient(145deg, #0755ba 30%, #e7f1fe 100%);
    }
    @media (min-width: 1000px) {
      /* load on wide screens */
      body {
        background-color: transparent;
        background-size: cover;
      }
    }
    button {
      background-color: #1676f4;
    }
    #logo {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 60px;
      height: 60px;
      border-radius: 100%;
      background-size: contain;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
      box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    }

  /* Layout */
  *, *:before, *:after {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
  html, body {
   height: 100%;
   font: 100 16px/1.55 "Open Sans", sans-serif;
   margin: 0;
  }
  #info {
       color: #fff;
       text-align: center;
       padding: 28px;
  }
  #form {
   height: 100%;
   display: flex;
   background-color: #fff;
   justify-content: center;
    }
    
    /* Responsive behaviour */ 
  @media (max-width: 1000px) {
    h2 {
        display: none;
      }
  }
  
  @media (min-width: 1001px) {
     body {
       display: flex;
       align-items: center;
       justify-content: center;
     }
     #logo {
       width:96px;
        height:96px;
     }
     #info, #form {
       height: 450px;
       box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
     }
     #info {
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
       width: 465px;
       border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
     }
     #form {
       width: 320px;
       padding: 28px;
       border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
     }
    }
  
  /* Elements / components theme */
  
  h1 {
   font-size: 36px;
   font-weight: 100;
  } 
  h2 {
   font-size: 28px;
   font-weight: 100;
   margin-bottom: 14px;
  } 
  form {
   max-width: 320px;
  }
  label {
   font-size: 14px;
   padding: 16px 0 5px 0;
   display: inline-block; 
  } 
  input[type='text'],
  input[type='password'] {
   width: 100%;
   
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance: none;
   -ms-appearance: none;
   -o-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;
   
   font: inherit;
   font-size: 14px;
   
   height: 37px;
   border-radius: 4px;
   padding: 4px 9px;
   border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  }
  button {
   width:100%;
   margin-top: 37px;
   height: 37px;
   border: 1px solid #666;
   border-radius: 4px;
   background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 2%, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 98%);
   box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
   outline: none;
   cursor: pointer;
   color: #fff;
   text-align: center;
   position: relative;
   font: inherit;
   font-weight: 600;
  }
  #button-submit:focus:after {
   box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   top: -2px;
   right: -2px;
   bottom: -2px;
   left: -2px;
   border-radius: inherit;
  }
  .error input {
   display: block;
   border-color: red;
  }
  .error form:after {
   content: "The username and password you entered do not match our records. Please double-check and try again.";
   display: block;
   border: 1px solid red;
   border-radius: 4px;
   width: 100%;
   margin-top: 16px;
   font-size: 14px;
   padding: 8px;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
 <div id="form">
  <form method="post" action="" id="theform">
   <h2>Страница входа</h2>
   <label id="login-label" for="login">Логин</label>
   <input type="text" id="login" name="username" aria-labelledby="login-label" autofocus>
   <label id="password-label" for="password">Пароль</label>
   <input type="password" id="password" name="password" aria-labelledby="password-label">
   <button id="button-submit" type="submit">Войти</button>
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Что конкретно меня интересует. В 8 версии ваадина имеется LoginForm, с которым, якобы, браузеры умеют определять и сохранять поля login/password. На самом деле это работает только в Firefox, что меня не устраивает. С таким подходом, который представлен в приложении bakery, проблем в сохранении login/password не возникает. Но, быстро пробежав по всему демопроекту, я так и не нашёл, где и как именно используется LoginHtmlServlet. Никакой информации я так же не нашёл.
Итак, конкретный вопрос: как именно можно использовать сервлеты и ваадин проект одновременно, как можно из ваадин проекта на дополнительный сервлет.

В общем, как реализовать такой же вход в систему, как в демо проекте?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Демо проект использует Shiro для аутенфикации.

В папке `src\main\resources` лежит `shiro.ini`. В нем `shiro.loginURL=/login.html`. В `WebServlet` в [`urlPаtterns`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html) как раз и указан этот url.

> `@WebServlet(asyncSupported = true, urlPatterns = LoginHtmlServlet.LOGIN_HTML)`.

То есть страницy аутенфикации определяет Shiro (то есть делает первый redirect на `localhost:8080/login.html`.) Он же проверяет, если user/password совпадает. `LoginHtmlServlet` в зависимости от get/post пишет в стрим ответа страницу. Если авторизация не прошла --> `resp.sendRedirect(LOGIN_HTML + "?error");`

---

Использование несколько сервлетов в приложениее лучше всего описано здесь : [Mapping Sub-Paths](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/application/application-environment.html#application.environment.servlet-mapping.sub-paths)

Comment: Не подскажешь ли ещё, где можно найти информацию о подключении и настройке Shiro для Vaadin8 (если честно - то я в первый раз вообще услышал о Shiro))?

Comment: Хм, судя по всему, никого отдельного примера или даже документации нет. Единственное, где можно посмотреть, как работает- bakery, который Вы уже используете. Наверное, самый легкий способ начать просто копировать шаг за шагом, пока не начнет работать. Помимо этого, там еще `ShiroFilter` важный класс . А так, к сожалению, только кусочки примеров как здесь https://github.com/peterl1084/cdiexample

Comment: И на том спасибо) Уже хоть что-то